# systemd timer starts immediately

Tags: systemd-timer

I have a systemd timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=My timer
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Timer]
OnBootSec=10min
OnUnitInactiveSec=10min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

And a corresponding service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my-script.sh
```

Which runs every 10 minutes with no problems but it also runs immediately after the system has started whereas I expected the `OnBootSec` command to delay it for 10 minutes. What am I misunderstanding? This is on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `[Install]
WantedBy=mytimer.target` at the end of your unit file for your service?!

Comment: Apparently not as it works...  Isn't it implicit as long as the service and timer files have the same name?

Answer (score 0):

My bad - I had another service wanting this one. Changing that dependency to the timer fixed the problem. Ooops...

Update: The timer was working just fine. The service was being triggered because it was listed as a `Wants` dependency by another service. Changing that service to `Want` the timer instead fixed the problem.

Comment: Please update this in your questions, do not put is as answer. Or clarify in the answer what service and so on